# Is there a method for mapping AND reduction in a stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

#### Problem

I want to reduce a stream of `MatchResults` to a `String`. Is there a method in the standard-library for this or do I have to write a custom `Collector`?

Currently, my method looks like this:

```
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
    List<MatchResult> matches = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line).results() // Finds matches
            .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line))  // Filters out "quoted strings" and comments
            .toList();
    String underline = "";
    for (MatchResult m : matches)
        underline += " ".repeat(m.start() - underline.length()) + "^".repeat(m.end() - m.start());
    return line.strip() + "\n" + underline;
}
```

But with the proviced mapping methods I **cannot** write this:

```
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
    return line.strip() + "\n" + Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line).results() //
            .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line)) //
            .reduce("", (subtotal, elem) //
                -> subtotal + " ".repeat(elem.start() - subtotal.length()) + "^".repeat(elem.end() - elem.start());
}
```

...because both the subtotal and the element have to share the same type. Is there another method that I just don't know, that does this?

Edit:
The method underlines all occurences of the regex in the line without a few filtered exceptions.

#### Sample

Input:

- line: "I love food, food is cool!"
- regex: "food"

Output:

```
I love food, food is cool!
       ^^^^  ^^^^
```

Comment: Can you share a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Does your current non-streams method work if the line starts with white space?  Since no one really knows what the filter does, answers must include the final `line.strip` which may throw off the underline pattern.

Comment: @WJS Hence we should strip the line as the first step and then process it.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko normally I would agree.  But what does the OP really want to do?   There are other unknowns in the question and doing that may not work for the OP.   Imo, the question needs more information.

Comment: The filter is a method that removes "non-runnable code". This includes quoted strings and comments. I now realized that its irrelevant to the question but as multiple answers adress it, i will not remove it.

Comment: The strip at the start is used to remove unnecessary tabs that count as one character, but offset the whole string. Leading and trailing whitespaces are irrelevant for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this version of [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) :

```
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
    String underline = Pattern.compile(regex)
                              .matcher(line)
                              .results()
                              .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line))
                              .reduce("",
                                      (str,mr) -> str.concat(" ".repeat(mr.start() - str.length()) + "^".repeat(mr.end() - mr.start())),
                                      String::concat);
    return line.strip() + "\n" + underline;
}
```

To make it somehow readable you could extract the BiFunction:

```
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {

    BiFunction<String,MatchResult,String> func = (str,mr) ->
            str.concat(" ".repeat(mr.start() - str.length()) + "^".repeat(mr.end() - mr.start()));

    String underline = Pattern.compile(regex)
                              .matcher(line)
                              .results()
                              .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line))
                              .reduce("",func::apply, String::concat);

    return line.strip() + "\n" + underline;
}
```

Comment: I asked the OP regarding the final strip.  If the filter doesn't remove the Match results for leading white space it will throw off the pattern.  Regardless +1 for the answer.

Comment: @WJS By the way, the question and this answer led me to an interesting observation: streams produced by the Regex Engine (obtained via `results()`, `splitAsStream()`) are actually "not parallelizable", meaning if we apply `parallel()` it would not change the behavior of the stream, only one thread would be occupied and *combiner* would not be invoked.  Stream becomes parallel only if an operation that buffers the whole contents (like `distinct()` or `sorting()`) gets invoked.

Comment: I clearly hadn't consider that.  But it is interesting.  Imo, it's also unfortunate that one must resort to the three argument reduce when all that is needed is a two argument version that supports a `BiFunction` instead of a `BinaryOperator`.

Comment: Don’t write `func::apply` when you have a `BiFunction` and a method expecting a `BiFunction`; just use `func`. But I don’t think that this function meets the *associativity* constraint.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this

```java
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
    String stripppedLine = line.strip();
    char[] array = new char[stripppedLine.length()];
    Arrays.fill(array, ' ');
    Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(stripppedLine).results()
        .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), stripppedLine))
        .forEach(mr -> Arrays.fill(array, mr.start(), mr.end(), '^'));
    return new StringBuilder(stripppedLine).append('\n').append(array).toString();
}
```

Note that here, the operations are truly independent of the processing order and do not interfere. So in theory, you could run this stream in parallel and get the correct result, but considering ordinary line string sizes, this won’t give you a benefit.

Still, you might be more efficient with a plain loop:

```java
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
    line = line.strip();
    int len = line.length();
    char[] array = new char[len * 2 + 1];
    line.getChars(0, len, array, 0);
    array[len] = '\n';
    Arrays.fill(array, len + 1, array.length, ' ');
    for(Matcher mRes = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line); mRes.find(); )
        if(ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line))
            Arrays.fill(array, len + mRes.start(), len + mRes.end(), '^');
    return new String(array);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I preferred your loop version.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your original question and subsequent comments, I would just use a regular loop to accomplish it.  In this version I don't remove anything from the original string.

```
String line = "   to be or not to    be that is the question.                ";
String regex = "to\\s+be";
String result = pointUnderlineRunnables(line, regex);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
   to be or not to    be that is the question.                
   ^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^
```

- first establish a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) with the provided arguments.
- instantiate a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder()) to hold the underline.
- the iterate over the matches using `Matcher.find()`
- The operation is:

  - append blanks up to the start of the match.
  - now append "^" for a length of match using `Matcher.group().length()`
- return the original and underline separated by a new line.

```
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
       Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     
       while (m.find()) {
           sb.append(" ".repeat(m.start()-sb.length()));
           sb.append("^".repeat(m.group().length()));
       }
       
       return line + "\n" + sb.toString();
}
```

Note that since `StringBuilder` returns its own reference via append I could have combined the two appends.  But I think the above is clearer.

Comment: This task is definitely more suitable for the old plain imperative programming style.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko there seems to be some obsession with the `String.repeat` method in all answers. You [can express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73106730/2711488) the operation as a stream operation without dependencies to the preceding element. Still, for processing a single line string, this might be too much overhead.

Answer (score 2):

## StringBuilder & collect

We can use the method [`collect(supplier,accumulator,combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) to build the underline string ( *//* edited based on the suggestions given by *@Holger*).

This method needs to be provided with the following arguments:

- *Mutable container* - in this case an instance of `StringBuilder` having the length equal to the length of the given string, filled with white spaces;
- *Accumulator* - a function responsible for accumulating the result;
- *Combiner* - a function that describes how to merge *containers* holding partial results while executing the stream in parallel.

In a nutshell, the idea is to create a `StringBuilder` filled with white spaces and having length equal to the length of the given string, and for every `MatchResult` replace the chunk in of the `StringBuilder` corresponding to its `start` and `end` with a string comprised of caret symbols `^`.

That's how it can be implemented:

```
public static String pointUnderlineRunnables(String line, String regex) {
    String normalizedLine = line.strip();
    
    return new StringBuilder(normalizedLine)
        .append("\n")
        .append(helper(normalizedLine, regex))
        .toString();
}

public static CharSequence helper(String line, String regex) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line).results()                 // Finds matches
        .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line)) // Filters out "quoted strings" and comments
        .collect(
            () -> new StringBuilder(" ".repeat(line.length())),
            (StringBuilder res, MatchResult next) ->
                res.replace(next.start(), next.end(), "^".repeat(next.end() - next.start())),
            (left, right) -> IntStream.range(0, line.length())
                .filter(i -> right.charAt(i) == '^')
                .forEach(i -> left.setCharAt(i, '^'))
        );
}
```

#### CharBuffer & collect

Here's another flavor of the `helper()` implemented using `CharBuffer`:

```
public static CharSequence helper(String line, String regex) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line).results()                 // Finds matches
        .filter(mRes -> ProgramHelper.isRunnableCode(mRes.start(), line)) // Filters out "quoted strings" and comments
        .collect(
            () -> {
                char[] arr = new char[line.length()];
                Arrays.fill(arr, ' ');
                return CharBuffer.wrap(arr);
            },
            (CharBuffer buf, MatchResult next) -> IntStream.range(next.start(), next.end())
                .forEach(i -> buf.put(i, '^')),
            (left, right) -> IntStream.range(0, line.length())
                .filter(i -> right.get(i) == '^')
                .forEach(i -> left.put(i, '^'))
        );
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(pointUnderlineRunnables("I love food, food is cool!", "food"));
}
```

***Output** (with `filter` operation commented out):*

```
I love food, food is cool!
       ^^^^  ^^^^
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tyd)

Comment: I see, you also expressed the accumulator function in a way that does not depend on the previous element. You could also use a merge function like `{ IntStream.range(0, line.length()) .filter(i -> right.charAt(i) == '^') .forEach(i -> left.setCharAt(i, '^')); return left; }`…

Comment: @Holger Thanks. It's more concise and allows using the flavor of `collect` expecting three arguments instead of declaring a custom collector. I was thinking about that, but hesitated whether it's a justifiable case to utilize `forEach`.

Comment: @Holger I'm also interested to know your opinion about this approach with `CharBuffer` https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tyd

Comment: Using a `CharBuffer` works, but adds no advantage over a plain array. In fact, it requires you to resort to `IntStream.range(next.start(), next.end()).forEach(i -> buf.put(i, '^')` where a plain array allows to use `Arrays.fill` which is not only simpler but will likely get optimized specially by the JVM. But in all cases, you don’t need `toString()` in your `helper` method. Change the return type to `CharSequence` or `char[]` and the caller to `return new StringBuilder().append( normalizedLine).append("\n").append(helper(normalizedLine, regex)).toString();` avoiding the intermediate `String`.

Comment: @Holger `Change the return type to CharSequence or char[]` - Good point. Updated the answer.